# Jupyter Running Wrong Cell in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the Jupyter extension on VSCode, Windows 10. I'm using Python through Anaconda.

I'm using a jupyter notebook and am running several different cells. After I run some of the cells a few times and restart the kernel a few times (to allow modules that I edited to update for the notebook), the notebook eventually stops running the correct cell. No matter what cell I try to run, it always runs the same cell, which is directly below my most used cell/the cell I used last. Opening and closing VSCode works but is only a temporary solution, and the issue has been arising more often. Does anyone know how to fix this?